# Unterminated quoted string in Capistrano curl command

Tags: ruby, capistrano, cloudflare

I've tried just about every combination of single quotes, double quotes and backslashes that I can think of. If anyone could please point out what I'm doing wrong that'd be greatly appreciated.

```
run_locally do
    execute "\\curl -X POST \"https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/#{fetch(:cloudflare_zone)}/purge_cache\" \
    -H \"X-Auth-Email: test@example.com\" \
    -H \"X-Auth-Key: #{fetch(:cloudflare_api)}\" \
    -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" \
    --data {\"purge_everything\":true}\""
end
```

My capistrano script dies when it hits this every time. I feel like it's that last line but I'm not sure why.

Edit: I've gotten past that error, but now get "Malformed JSON in request body" back from Cloudflare.

```
run_locally do
            execute "\\curl -X POST \"https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/#{fetch(:cloudflare_zone)}/purge_cache\" \
    -H \"X-Auth-Email: test@example.com\" \
    -H \"X-Auth-Key: #{fetch(:cloudflare_api)}\" \
    -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" \
    --data \"{\"purge_everything\":true}\" "
end
```

So for some reason it doesn't like my --data section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to check this directly for you, but you can use other string constructs to do this in a clearer way which will hopefully highlight the issue for you.

```
run_locally do
  execute %{curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/#{fetch(:cloudflare_zone)}/purge_cache" \
    -H "X-Auth-Email: test@example.com" \
    -H "X-Auth-Key: #{fetch(:cloudflare_api)}" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{"purge_everything":true}'}
  end
```

It's probably the nested double quotes in your JSON causing the issue.